# Moving Column names to rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have such a table with date as column name[image]

but I would like to have these dates in one column in more than one row something like this:

```
Date       Index
20170806   9206
20170813   8041
20170820   8861
20170827   8356
```

How can I do it in SQL Server

Comment: Look at using pivot - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx . But having data in the structure you have seems like it will cause you a lot of grief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to go for more dynamic solution rather than hard coding all columns, the below scripts should work:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TestTable') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE TestTable;

CREATE TABLE TestTable
(
    [20170806] INT NOT NULL,
    [20170813] INT NOT NULL,
    [20170820] INT NOT NULL,
    [20170827] INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (9206, 8041, 8861, 8356)


DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @sql  NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME)
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.[COLUMNS] AS c
WHERE  c.TABLE_NAME = 'TestTable'

SET @sql = '
SELECT [Date],
       [Index]
FROM   TestTable 
       UNPIVOT([Index] FOR [Date] IN ('+ @cols +')) AS up'

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNPIVOT` for this.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
UNPIVOT([Date] For [Index] IN( [20170806], [20170813], [20170820], [20170827])) UNPVT
```

In addition, if you want to make it dynamically, you can use this query too.

```
DECLARE @ColNames NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    = STUFF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
        (SELECT T.* FROM (VALUES(1)) AS DUMY(ID) LEFT JOIN MyTable T ON 1=2 FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS XSINIL )
        ,'<T xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">','')
        ,'</T>','')
        ,'_x0032_','2')
        ,' xsi:nil="true"/>','] ')
        ,'<',',[') ,1,1,'')


DECLARE @SqlQ NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable UNPIVOT([Date] For [Index] IN( ' + @ColNames  + ')) UNPVT'

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlQ
```

Comment: will more useful, if u make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pivot such as:

However, i dont know your exact table names

```
select field_names
from table_name
pivot
( index
for index in ( Date, Index)
) pivot
```

but a useful article to follow is

"https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx"

Answer (score 0):

Designed the table (variable) structure as below. 
Hopefully, it matches your table structure.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE
(
    [20170806] INT,
    [20170813] INT,
    [20170820] INT,
    [20170827] INT
)

INSERT INTO @data VALUES (9206, 8041, 8861, 8356)

SELECT * FROM @data
```

You can use [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) statement for this. [If you have dynamic columns, check this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48393/passing-column-names-dynamically-to-unpivot).

```
SELECT [Date],[Index]
FROM
@data  
UNPIVOT 
(
  [Index] FOR [Date] IN ([20170806], [20170813], [20170820], [20170827])
) AS unpivotTable;
```

and the output is

[image]